# In pandas, how to get 2nd mode

Tags: python, pandas

So I'm generating a `summary report` from a `data set`. I used `.describe()` to do the heavy work but it doesn't generate everything I need i.e. the second most common thing in the data set.

I noticed that if I use `.mode()` it returns the most common value, is there an easy way to get the second most common?

Comment: I am posting a solution, but it may be helpful to other readers to post the relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 6):

```
df['column'].value_counts()
```

What this does, according to the docs:

> The resulting object will be in descending order so that the first
>   element is the most frequently-occurring element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

1. Create a duplicate data set.
2. Use `.mode()` to find the most common value.
3. Pop all items with that value from the set.
4. Run `.mode()` again on the modified data set.

Comment: any other idea, without popping value

Answer (score 0):

> > df

```
    A
0   a
1   b
2   c
3   d
4   g
5   a
6   b
7   b
8   c
9   c
10  c
```

**Through Counter:** If you want to grab mode and it's count alone, can go for this method.

> > from collections import Counter
> >
> > Counter(df['A']).most_common()

[('c', 4), ('b', 3), ('a', 2), ('d', 1), ('g', 1)]

> > Counter(df['A']).most_common()[1]

('b', 3)

**Through value_counts():** If you want to view all the counts in a table format, go for this.

> > df['A'].value_counts()

```
c    4
b    3
a    2
d    1
g    1
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
df['column'].value_counts().index.tolist()[1]
```

this will get the 2nd mode, increase the number at the end to get 3rd, 4th, etc
Value_counts() lists the amount of time each value appears descending by the amount of times it appears, so the first item would be the mode. but if you just do  `df['column'].value_counts()[1]` it just prints out the number of times it comes up and not the value, so by getting the index and then turning it into a list, you get the heading of the value

Comment: Can you explain what your code does step by step?